# Ввод заготовленного текста в input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Мне необходимо ввести заранее подготовленное значение в input(), которое пользователь может поменять, пример:

```py
name = input('Ваш ник: ', 'TopMinecrafter2015')
```

Вывод:
`Ваш ник:` *TopMinecrafter2015*

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: @S.Nick Тут не написано как добавить заготовленный текст. Выходит это невозможно?

Comment: В стандартном `input` такого нет.

Comment: это она, [XY Problem](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/420098)? PS @Zoom, можете описАть, зачем вам это понадобилось?

Comment: @Jack_oS Мне кажется в этом нет ничего такого, что вызывало бы вопросы. Но объясню. Человек может ввести IP в input, но если человек до этого его вводил, то он автоматически вставляется в input

Comment: "если человек до этого его вводил"... теперь вопросов стало еще больше: какова логика программы (в общих чертах); как вы сохраняете данные, введенные пользователями; почему бы перед input-ом не проверить, есть ли там IP?

Comment: @Jack_oS Если человек ввёл IP, то он сохраняется в конфиг. При следующем запуске если ему предлагают прошлый IP, но он может его сменить. Лучше всего это понятно на моём примере с ником.

Answer (score 1):

В стандартной функции input такого нет, однако можно использовать следующий код:

```
name = input('Ваш ник: ') or 'TopMinecrafter2015'
```

Тогда, если пользователь ничего не введет, переменная получит значение 'TopMinecrafter2015'

Answer (score 0):

Установите библиотеку:

```
pip install Inline-input
```

---

Простой пример:

```
import inline #Импортируем библиотеку
input = inline.input #Заменяем стандартный input

name = input("Ваш ник: ", inp="TopMinecrafter2015") #вы сможете редактировать текст указанный в inp
```

---

Вы также можете скрыть свой ник во время ввода, ограничить длину ника или создать автодополнение для него, [подробнее.](https://pypi.org/project/Inline-input/)